# How can we plot multiple lines of a function with a for loop to minimize the coding?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
def k(x,b):
    return x**b

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

L = k(x,1)
plt.plot(x,L, label = 'n=1')


L2 = k(x,2)
plt.plot(x,L2, label = 'n=2')

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to plot multiply polynomials of `x^b`.

I can plot the function for different `b` values, but I need to make the code more efficient by using a for loop, or a good method to change the `b` value and then plot them into one graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
def k(x,b):
    return x**b

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
for n in range(1, 3):
    L = k(x,n)
    plt.plot(x,L, label = f'n={n}')

# To add the legend:
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting figure]

Answer (score 2):

Check the `plot` docs.  I believe `y` (2nd argument) can be (n,m) shape, where `n` is the same size as `x`, and `m` the number of lines you want to draw:

```
In [156]: x = np.linspace(0,10,11) 
In [160]: y = x[:,None]**np.array([1,2,3])                                                       
In [161]: y                                                                                      
Out[161]: 
array([[   0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   1.,    1.,    1.],
       [   2.,    4.,    8.],
       [   3.,    9.,   27.],
       [   4.,   16.,   64.],
       [   5.,   25.,  125.],
       [   6.,   36.,  216.],
       [   7.,   49.,  343.],
       [   8.,   64.,  512.],
       [   9.,   81.,  729.],
       [  10.,  100., 1000.]])
In [162]: plt.plot(x, y)                                                                         
Out[162]: 
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff738082940>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff738082a90>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff738082be0>]
```

Check the `plot` docs on how to provide labels for multiple lines.

The `y` calculation takes advantage of `numpy` `broadcasting`, allowing us to work with 2 1d arrays, producing a new 2d array.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it is most efficient in both terms of performance and development time, +1 from me

Comment: @WilliamMiller, but I didn't include the figure. :)

Comment: Or links to the documentation - I mean come on it’s really hard to find the `matplotlib.pyplot.plt` page sometimes.... I’m going to have to rescind my upvote, this is just sloppy

Answer (score 0):

> I can plot the function for different b values, but I need to make the code more efficient by using a for loop or a good method to change the b value and then plot them into one graph.

A loop will not make your code more efficient. By definition:

> ef·fi·cient
>
> (especially of a system or machine) achieving maximum productivity with minimum wasted effort or expense

A loop, along with your wrappers are wasted efforts. It makes your code much harder to read, maintain, and also more expensive to compute as it means more frames to initialize. As stated in [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Simple is better than complex.

There is absolutely no reason why you should not simply write:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
plt.plot(x, x**1, label='n=1')
plt.plot(x, x**2, label='n=2')

plt.show()
```

Comment: The code will be more efficient: less lines is more readable and so more maintainable.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, I fail to understand how adding unnecessary layers would improve efficiency in any way based on the provided code. A loop for 2 calls, along with an operator wrapper is more than redundant in my opinion.

Comment: The goal here is not to make the code faster, the goal is to have less code. If you want to have n go up to 100, your solution would require a lot of coding and thus wasted time

Comment: Yes, *if*. But based on the provided code, it is redundant.

Comment: It was the minimal reproducable question.

Comment: @Nathan The loop is wholly unnecessary in this case - plotting multiple sets of `y` values against a common set of `x` values is handled by matplotlib internally (as hpaulj pointed out in his answer). However, Jordan, it is still better practice than writing a different `plot` statement for every set of `y` values, and would be the best practice for the case of plotting multiple sets of `y` values against different sets of `x` values. The loop is generalizable, writing each individual call to `plot` is an antipattern.