# making multiple graphs with a for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to create multiple Monte Carlo analyses for 10 different companies. The MC function has 3 parameters that change depending on the company, and the code for it looks like this:

```
import numpy as np


def monte_carlo(start_price, days, mu, sigma):
    price = np.zeros(days)
    price[0]= start_price
    shock = np.zeros(days)
    drift = np.zeros(days)

    for x in range (1,days):
        shock[x] = np.random.normal(loc = mu *dt, scale = sigma * np.sqrt(dt) )

        drift[x] = mu*dt

        price[x] = price[x-1] + (price[x-1] * (drift[x] + shock[x]) )
    return price
```

This function is then plotted 100 times by a for loop:

```
for run in range(100):
        plt.plot(monte_carlo(start_price,days,mu,sigma))
        plt.xlabel('Days')
        plt.ylabel('Price')
        plt.title('MCA for ')
```

this all works fine for one set of values for start_price, mu, sigma, but I want it to loop thru 10 different sets.

I have something that looks like this:

```
for stock in start_price, sigma, mu:
    for run in range(100):
        plt.plot(monte_carlo(start_price[stock],days,mu[stock],sigma[stock]))
        plt.xlabel('Days')
        plt.ylabel('Price')
        plt.title('MCA for %' %stock)
```

but that doesn't work at all, I get a ' Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only ' error.

I hope that this makes sense, I'm a complete noob so any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we plot multiple lines of a function with a for loop to minimize the coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830335/how-can-we-plot-multiple-lines-of-a-function-with-a-for-loop-to-minimize-the-cod)

Comment: I think if you print `stock` you'll soon find out your problem

Comment: @Nathan i don't see the problem after doing that, i get my 3 separate data frames of mu sig and start price but I don't really understand what that's telling me

Comment: So what does start_price[stock] do?